# google app engine: how to run different version

Tags: google-app-engine

Suppose I uploaded another version (say, "version: 2" in file app.yaml ) of my Google App Engine application. Version 1 is still the default and version 2 is for testing. How do I run it then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you upload a `version` on Appengine, you can switch between them easily.

Say that your app name is myapp, currently running version 1. You also have uploaded a version called 2-testing. Your default app (with version 1) can be reached by accessing `myapp.appspot.com`

If you wanted to access your versions explicitly, you joust need to access `<version_name>-dot-myapp.appspot.com`. Following the example it would be:

`1-dot-myapp.appspot.com` or `2-testing-dot-myapp.appspot.com`

The `-dot-` is equivalent to `<version>.<appname>` but allows you to correctly serve a secure application with SSL

You can mark any version you want as `default` (serving `myapp.appspot.com`) using the [admin console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/)

edit: this is the official [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Requests_and_Domains) talking about domains and subdomains in Appengine

Comment: the better sytax is 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com or 2-dot-myapp.appspot.com etc so that the certificates work correctly for SSL.

Comment: yeah, you're right :) I'll edit my post with the improved version, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Under versions in your admin console you can find the live uri of a version, if you select the version.

And you can use traffic splitting, where you can use your own client ip or a cookie to test a version.
Docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting