# Uploading different versions in GAE in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm writing a GAE project in Java and now, I'm trying to create a different version to use it for testing future changes.

I read about modules, [`app-engine-web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref)..., but I can't find how to deploy two versions.
I have seen posts that say that you can access it by changing the url:

```
"version"."app_id".app...
```

But I don't know what files have I to modify.

Comment: Similar question already answered see this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060867/google-app-engine-how-to-run-different-version, In java instead of `app.yaml` change version in `web-inf/appengine-web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref) you can use the version tag to specify a version.  Likewise when deploying using appcfg you can use the -v argument  to override that value with a different version.

So one approach is to have a production version specified in the config file and a testing version you deploy with

```
appcfg -v test_version ...
```